# Can PHP's exec() run a node module?

Tags: php, npm, exec, google-slides-api

I want to display the output of the command on a PHP page using `exec()` function. If I run the command in ubuntu's terminal that's working fine but not in PHP code. md2gslides is a library that converts .md (markdown) files to google slides using Google Slides API. I installed md2gslides using npm. Below is the piece of code I wrote:

```
$output=array();
exec('"/home/user/.npm-global/bin/md2gslides" "/var/www/html/test/files/slides.md" --copy=1z3XLhVWc03U3deHy --title "Test Slide" --no-browser 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
Array
(
[0] => internal/validators.js:125
[1] => throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
[2] => ^
[3] =>
[4] => TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
[5] => at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
[6] => at Object.join (path.js:1147:7)
[7] => at Object. (/home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/md2gslides/bin/md2gslides.js:33:38)
[8] => at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
[9] => at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
[10] => at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[11] => at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
[12] => at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
[13] => at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
[14] => at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[15] => at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
)
```

Any hints here?

Comment: seems like its missing the local variable path from the user?

Comment: I did not understand. which local variable path you are referring to?

Comment: unix shell...  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined... but never mind i guess its the first parameter... you dont need to put quotes around parameter and binary.. try removing the double quotes

Comment: tried that too..didn't work.